# Altium designer, The designator does not update when using update from libraries

Tags: schematics, altium, library, update, designer

I am fairly new to this forum and to altium designer. I am having a problem updating a transistor designator from Q? to T?. When I use the update from library in the tools menu, all the parameters update except the designator. Could some one assist me with this problem, please? I'vd looked in all the forums. But I couldn't find anyone who had the same problem as me.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you update from libraries make sure the "Fully replace..." box is checked. I believe this should update the designator, provided you have the "T?" specified in the library symbol properties.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to save library and whole project first. Sometimes Altium does thinks like this if project is unsaved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it changes any part of the annotation/designators when you update the symbol from a library. You can manually edit it, use find similar object to reset the designators etc.

Answer (score 0):

Bringing this up again because it is still a problem and I had to find a work around. I am using Altium 19 and had the same issues. I found that the best solution was to use the Find and Replace Text option, which is CTRL-H, then specify "Designators" as the identifier. (https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/sch-dlg-findandreplacetextfind-and-replace-text-ad)[image: If you only want to update certain components check "Prompt On Replace"]